# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 7680 bytes) in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am transferring my code to another domain in wordpress. I did all the configuration very well. But I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12 bytes) in /home/nileshna/public_html/hdsystems.com.au/wp-includes/default-widgets.php
```

I have tried every possible soluitons. 
I have changed `memory_limit = 512M` in php.ini file.
I have changes the limit in .htaccess file too and define maximum size using this code `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');` in wp-config.php file too. But still no output.

Please help me. I spent almost 2 to 3 hrs on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is wordpress really so heavy, that uses those amounts of memory? :O

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I talked to them they told me to change the value in php.ini file. But still no output. I also tried that option in wp-config.php file.